# How can this table possibly be converted to a MySql table?

Tags: mysql, table

I got a TABLE in Excel format like:
[image]

This is a **STEN TABLE** containing `FACTORS (A,B,C,D,E....etc)`

Each **Factor** is like a separate test.

Each **Factor** *i.e. Factor A* has a `[Raw Score]` and a `[Sten]`

Supposing **Factor A**, had a question like:

```
-----------------------------------
```

**Why do humans have Eyes?**

*The answer options could be like:*

> **a)** To Watch movies =  *[Raw Score] -> 10,*
>
> **b)** To Read Novels  =  *[Raw Score] -> 5,*
>
> **c)** To close them while sleeping = *[Raw Score] ->0*

So if they Chose **a)** then, the system will go to the `STEN TABLE` to get the `STEN` Equivalent under `Factor A`, in this case, the **sten** equivalent will be `4`. `(See Factor A->Row score 10-> Sten column)`

What could be the most practical way to have this STEN TABLE with Factors and their Raw Scores and Stens created?

Smothing like

```
              **STEN TABLE**
                         |
                         |
                **FACTORS (A,B,C,D...)**
                      /     \
                     /       \
                    /         \
                   /           \
                  /             \
            **[Raw Score]      [Sten]**
```

---

**EDIT 1:**

> To See a larger image, please click here: http://ctrlv.in/459785

Please note that, the `sten`s are not equal for all **Factors**, though the `Raw Scores` are the same. *i.e.* in **Factor A**, `[Raw Score]->3 = [sten]->2` but in **Factor C**  `[Raw Score]->3  = [sten]->1` and in **Factor F**  `[Raw Score]->1 [sten]->2` whereas in **Factor E**  `[Raw Score]->1 = [sten]->1`.

Thank you.

Any Suggestion is highly honored.

Comment: To a larger image, please click here:http://ctrlv.in/459785

Answer (score 1):

I'd pull this data into two tables: `Factor's` and `STEN Lookup's`.

Your Factors table would look like:

```
Factor_ID(PK) | Factor_Name
--------------|------------
  1           |      A
  2           |      B
  3           |      C
  4           |      D
```

Your `STEN_Lookup'

```
Factor_ID(FK) | Score_Value | STEN_Value
--------------|-------------|-------------
  1           |       0     |       1
  1           |       1     |       1
  1           |       2     |       1
  1           |       3     |       2
  1           |       4     |       2
  2           |       0     |       8
  2           |       1     |       9
  2           |       2     |       11
.....
```

I'd suggest you do some reading on normalization, as it helps massivly when designing your tables. A great Video Resource is [MVA, (Video 2 on this hyperlink)](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/database-fundamentals).

Comment: Thanks for the Idea, but please not that the `sten` values are not equal for all `Factors`. Please see EDIT 1... Thank you –

Comment: PLease click here to see a larger image: http://ctrlv.in/459785

Comment: @UniversalGrasp Please look in detail to STEN_Lookup table- you can set different values for each score AND factor. His solution is ok with your reqirements. It is just that the PK is (Factor_ID, Score_Value).

Comment: I've just made it a little clearer so you can see. In cases where the STEN_Value differs from the previous factor score, you just need to change the data. So for Factor 2 students a score of one gives a STEN of 9, but for Factor 1 Students a score of one gives a STEN of one.

Comment: @KidCode Thank You... So if I understand your suggestion well, you mean, `Fact_ID->1`=`Score_Value->[0 OR 1 OR 2 OR..4]` = `STEN_Value->[1 OR ...2]`... This is Super great, however, following this, then we might have an issue with FactorB because, it's `STEN_Value` will start from `8`instead of `1`: i.e `Fact_ID->2`=`Score_Value->[0]` = `STEN_Value->[8]` which is meant to be `Fact_ID->2`=`Score_Value->[0]` = `STEN_Value->[1]`.... Thanks again though.